# Prove that $x\cdot y=0 \iff x=0$ or $y=0$ without cases

Tags: abstract-algebra, alternative-proof

I have proved that given $x,y \in F$, $F$ a field, $x\cdot y=0 \iff x=0$ or $y=0$ by making cases for neither $x$ nor $y$ equals $0$ (and did a proof by contradiction) and then two cases for $x=0$ and $y=0$ (direct proofs).

As a matter of style, I'm not a big fan of either proofs by cases or proofs by contradiction.  Is there some slick way to avoid both and do a direct proof in 1 case that establishes this result?

Comment: I think it is fairly hard to avoid cases if even the problem statement ($x=0$ or $y=0$) uses cases, but interesting question!

Comment: Contradiction is not needed.  But that is not interesting, a proof is a proof is a proof. On to the next result.

Comment: This property follows from the cancellation property that all integral domains (of which fields form a subclass) have.  The cancellation law (that ab=ac implies b=c) is axiomatic for integral domains, and hence for fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the statement $A\implies (B\lor C)$ is actually equivalent to the statement $$A\land \neg B\implies C$$

So you don't have to separate cases. You can prove that if $x\cdot y=0$ and $x\neq 0$, then $y=0$. By doing so, you prove the statement $$x\cdot y=0\implies x=0\lor y=0$$

The other direction is obvious.

Comment: I didn't think to try to prove a logically equivalent statement.  Cool.  Thanks!  I will accept when it lets me.